# Android: How to update state of one view based on the state of other

Tags: android, android-layout, statelistdrawable

I am facing this issue for which the solution might just be a simple one, but my tries have not succeeded.
I have a parent view container which contains three child views which have their on onClick event handlers declared and perform different actions.
What I am trying to do is add statelist drawables to each of these so that for different states the colors of the child views change.
This is what it looks like roughly -
[image]

Child View 3 has it own statelist and works independently and I have what I need.
However, what I want is the state of child view 1 and 2 should change simultaneously when the state of either is changed while they perform their independent actions on click. So basically, if I am pressing (pressed state) child view 1 which changes its color maybe, the same should happen for 2 as well and vice versa. All this while, child view 3 should be unaffected.
I tried a number of ways to workaround with statelist drawables but with no success. Can anyone please help me out with this issue?
I believe there should be some elegant way to handle this in Android.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about to implement an interface, kinda:

```
OnStateChangeListener() {
    onStateChanged(int color, int whatever);
}
```

for both of related views and to listen each other state changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer all this to be done directly in your drawable, it is not possible.

I am sure there are other ways but three on a first glimpse:

1. You may use a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) and then use 
   [RadioButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) instances

   - this will require default RadioButton style changes
2. You can create a custom view container (derived from `LinearLayout` for example) and then add logic in it to deal with clicks from its child views

   - use [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) source as a reference how Google did it
3. You can use [GreenRobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or any other bus to dispatch an event from your clicked view and any other views can listen and change their own states

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function like this-

```
public void setStates(View views[],int clickedViewID){

for(int i=0;i<views.length;i++){
if(views[i].getID==clickedViewID){
//change color
}
else{
// do whatever like chnage color.
views[i].
}
}
}
```

pass all the three child views and the id of the clicked view.

Here than you can check the id of the three view if it is matched than change the color of that only otherwise anyhting else for all other views.